# Is there a way to manually invoke the on-screen keyboard?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Some apps, like Firefox (as [covered in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759598/ubuntu-touch-no-onscreen-keyboard-in-firefox)) don't trigger the on-screen keyboard. I have had other situations, e.g. when switching between apps and in LibreOffice (which is an X app, but like Firefox ships with Ubuntu Touch).

Is there a manual switch can somehow be invoked to toggle the onscreen keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I use ubuntu on most of my computers, but I am currently using Zorin OS on my touchscreen PC.  On the chance it's similar I will post some SS of how I trigger the on screen keyboard from the monitor.

If it doesn't work let me know and I can install Ubuntu and play with it.

[Find your status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVViU.jpg)

[Select the keyboard & choose the icon representing the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odbmi.jpg)

It should appear.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this applies to Touch.

Comment: You are talking about using a touchscreen pc, right?

Comment: Yes Ubuntu Touch. Not 'Ubuntu'.

Answer (score 0):

BQ Aquaris M10 Ubuntu Edition User Manual, p. 47:

Some apps like GIMP, **LibreOffice** and Xchat-Gnome are designed to be used in convergent mode only — the keyboard will not open in tablet mode.

This is expected behaviour.

I'm not sure you can call for a virtual keyboard manually. At least for now.

Comment: There's a user manual! That would have been useful to know about. Thanks!

Comment: The manual can be found here: https://it-bqcom15-media.s3.amazonaws.com/prod/resources/manual/Aquaris_M10_Ubuntu_Edition_Complete_User_Manual-1460548936.pdf

 from this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/759793/aquarius-m10-ubuntu-edition-user-manual